# Download image file from datapath stored in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

I am creating a web form application that allows a user to upload image file to a folder and store its path in a database. There is a data-list that is populated by the image path. I want the functionality to download image when it is selected from data-list. I am new to it and didn't get clear guidance from other questions.

Kindly help me.

Here is my code for uploading file

```
try
{
    if (FileUploadzz.HasFile)
    {

        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        string strguid = g.ToString();
        string uniqueString = strguid + FileUploadzz.FileName;

        FileUploadzz.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\AllUploads\AllUserImages\" + uniqueString));
        DataClasses1DataContext db2 = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        Picture p = new Picture();
        p.picturePath = "http://localhost:12237/AllUploads//AllUserImages/" + uniqueString;

        db2.Pictures.InsertOnSubmit(p);
        db2.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

I have a button in my datalist itemtemplate that I want to use for downloading that specific image I need help on downloading the image when button is clicked. I have image control and a button (button1) in item template of datalist. I have already populated my datalist succesfully with images. please let me know how to download that image on OnCLlick event of that button1.

Answer (score 0):

This code works in a way like you've to pass and image id to the function and w.r.t. that you can fetch specific image. This code will act like a base. If you want to fetch all the images at same time then still you can do using while loop. You can do deserializing one by one. So according to your purpose small changes need to be done.

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picImage;   

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReadImage", con);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbImageID.SelectedValue.ToString());



     SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

try
   {
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)

    con.Open();
     adp.Fill(dt);

   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
       {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["ImageData"]);

        picImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

        picImage.Image.Save(@"Complete path of location", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)//catch if any error occur
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)//check whether connection to database is open or not
                        con.Close();
                }
            }
```